# Read Status of Default Mediaplayer

Tags: android

I'm currently developing a custom SystemUI for Android, so I have no permission Problems.

I want a "Mediaplayer Widget" like on the Lockscreen. I think I can easily control the default Mediaplayer (or any Mediaplayer?) by injecting KeyEvents to the System.

My Problem is: How can I ensure to get updated about songchanges and opening/closing the Mediaplayer?.

**Update**

I found the Source of the ScreenLock and found the Code for `IRemoteControlDisplay` but now I dont't know how to use it. I tried to Debug it and it appears, that right after initalization, the `onListenerDetached` method gets called twice...

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be answered already. I just researched and got the following links that might help you.

It is clear that you have to work on running a service to monitor the changes using listeners such as: OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnErrorListener, OnInfoListener, OnPreparedListener.

[State change listener for MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101816/state-change-listener-for-mediaplayer)

[Android music player app: how to set a complete listener for media player that is running in a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184860/android-music-player-app-how-to-set-a-complete-listener-for-media-player-that-i)

Listen to volume changes:

[Is there a listener to listen for changes in the volume in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180279/is-there-a-listener-to-listen-for-changes-in-the-volume-in-android)

[Constantly check for volume change in Android services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207169/constantly-check-for-volume-change-in-android-services)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to work with a own MediaPlayer Object, I want to receive updates from any MediaPlayer (e.g. Google Play Music, Spirit, ... ) any MediaPlayer (App) that shows controls on the Lockscreen